# Facebook preview Open Graph Object Debugger

Tags: facebook, open-graph

if i try to publich my website on Facebook i have an error with the featured image.

I try to use the [facebook debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) but i not have any interest information.

I use this function but nothing resolve:

```
//* FACEBOOK *//

function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) // Se non è un post o una pagina
        return;

        $mytext=$post->post_excerpt;
        $myfulltext=strip_tags($post->post_content);
        if(strlen($mytext) > 250) $mytext = substr($mytext, 0, 250).'...';
        if(strlen($myfulltext) > 250) $myfulltext = substr($myfulltext, 0, 250).'...';
        if(empty($post->post_excerpt)) {
        $mytext=$myfulltext;
        }

        $mydesc=$mytext;
    $external_posts=$post->ID;

        echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="IDPAGE" />';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article" />';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . $mydesc . '" />';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '" />';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="TITLE WEBSITE" />';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<meta property="og:locale" content="it_IT" />';
        echo "\n";

        $myurl = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($external_posts), 'thumbnail' );
        $postimage=$myurl[0];

        if(empty($postimage)) {
        $default_image="URLIMAGE";
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '" />';
        }
        else {
        $default_image=$postimage;
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '" />';
        }
        echo "\n"; echo "\n";

}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 1 );
```

So i don't know how can i do to set a specific image. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: In your functions.php put this

```
function fb_excerpt($text, $excerpt) {
    if ($excerpt) return $excerpt;

    $raw_excerpt = $text;

    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
    $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if (count($words) > $excerpt_length) {
            array_pop($words);
            $text = implode(' ', $words);
            $text = $text . '...';
    } else { $text = implode(' ', $words); }

    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
```

and in your header.php between you `<head>` and `</head>` tags put this

```
<?php global $post;
if (is_singular()) { ?>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="522774907844630">
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo fb_excerpt($post->post_content, get_the_excerpt()); ?>">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This code will fail without a `global $post;`, you should consider using the `wp_head` hook instead to implement functionality in the header ( like the OP did in their question )

Comment: Oh. I wondered why would it fail because I dont have global $post anywhere but again, I have fallen for the [bones](http://themble.com/bones/) dilemma. I think I should develop on vanilla WP for a while before I keep answering here. Hah. Thanks for the input mate. Altough it would be fairly trivial to transfer this to the `wp_head` hook as well.